# Uploading a file to github with git

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, ssh

I have some question about Git. So, i have a file as database in my server. I want to upload the file to github repository to backup my database file. How this method? i'm using ssh in android.

I trying with `git push` its doesn't working.

Answer (score 0):

A `git push` in an Android shell supposed that you have done first:

- a `git init`
- a `git add yourFile`
- a `git commit -m "my File"`
- a ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" to generate a default SSH key pair
- a copy of the ~/.ssh/id_rsa to your GitHub User SSH setting page

All that to backup one file, which is not exactly what Git is well suited for.

Sending it to a third-party backup service (Microsoft OneDrive, Google Drive, Amanazon S3, ...) would be much quicker to do.